# Passing an async callback

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

I am unsure of how to pass an inline async callback to a function.

```
fraudListen = async () => {
    this.KYCinstance.events.ReportedFraud({fromBlock:0 }, (error, event) => { 
        returnVar = await doSomething();
        console.log(returnVar);
    }
}
```

I want to declare `(error, event)` to be an async function without having to declare it somewhere separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact function that wraps code that has an `await` inside has to be `async`.

```js
const fraudListen = () => {
  this.KYCinstance.events.ReportedFraud({ fromBlock: 0 }, async (error, event) => {
    returnVar = await doSomething();
    console.log(returnVar);
  });
};
```